# How to query specific columns on a OneToMany relationship using QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, querydsl

I want to perform a query in a OneToMany relationship. In the example below, a dog and a list of advantages for having him. More specifically, I want to query only a few attributes of Dog, as well as only a few attributes of Advantage. For this scenario, I created 2 DTOs to return what I need.
Furthermore, I want to query specific fields from a OneToOne relationship. I know that in this case I can simply put its desired attributes directly on the projection; however, I want to know if there is a more elegant way of doing it. There is also a DTO for this complex type.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_RACE")
public class Race {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String predominantColor;
    private boolean aggressive;
    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_ADVANTAGE")
public class Advantage {
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private int importance;
    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_DOG")
public class Dog {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean male;
    private Race race;
    private List<Advantage> advantages;
    // getters and setters
}

public class RaceDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9913068934589315984L;
    private String predominantColor;
    // getters and setters
}

public class AdvantageDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8813068934589315984L;
    private String description;
    // getters and setters
}

public class DogDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7713068934589315984L;
    private String name;
    private RaceDTO race;
    private List<AdvantageDTO> advantages;
    // getters and setters
}

@Repository
public DogRepository () {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private DSLQueryFactory queryFactory;

    // Getting dog with all of his info
    public Dog getAllDog(Long id) {
        final QDog qDog = new QDog("dog");
        final QAdvantage qAdv = new QAdvantage("adv");

        return this.createQueryJPA(qDog)
                .from(qDog)
                .leftJoin(qDog.advantages, qAdv).fetchJoin()
                .where(qDog.id.eq(id)).fetchOne();
    }

    // Getting dog with some of his info
    public DogDTO getPartialDog(Long id) {
        final QDog qDog = new QDog("dog");
        final JPAQuery<Dog> queryDog = this.queryFactory.queryJPA();

        // How do I get specific Dog columns along with specific
        // Advantage columns, in order to populate List<AdvantageDTO>
        // and RaceDTO? And also using fetchJoin()?
        Tuple tuple = queryChegada.select(qDog.name.as("name"), ??RaceDTO??, ??List<AdvantageDTO?? )
                .from(qDog)
                .where(qDog.id.eq(id)).fetchOne();

        DogDTO dto = new DogDTO();
        dto.setName(tuple.get("name"));
        dto.setRace(tuple.get(?????));
        dto.setAdvantages(tuple.get(?????));

        return dto;
    }
}
```

Using java 11, SpringBoot 2.5.12, Hibernate 5.4.33 and QueryDSL 4.4.0